# Henselization, localizations and diagonals: are these two rings the same?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, hensels-lemma

Let $k$ be a field (of characteristic zero if necessary, algebraically closed if necessary) and let $z\in k$.

Let $\phi:k[T]\rightarrow k[X,Y,...]$ be the $k$-morphism given by $T\mapsto X+Y$. Let $k[T]^h_{(T-z)}$ be the henselization of the localization at $(T-z)$ of $k[T]$. Can I identify the following two rings?
$$k[T]_{(T-z)}^h\otimes k[X,Y,\frac{1}{z-Y}]\overset{?}=k[T]_{(T-z)}^h\otimes k[X,Y,\frac{1}{X}]$$

(tensor products are taken over $k[T]$ with respect to $\phi$ and the inclusion of $k[T]$ in $k[T]^h_{(T-z)}$)

(Please, if someone has a better idea for the title feel free to edit!!)

EDIT:
The trick I want to use is that I (think I) can identify $k[T]_{(T-z)}^h$ with the algebraic part of $k[[T-z]]$ and I can "almost" use the formula
$$\frac{-1}{Y-z}=\frac{1}{X}\cdot\frac{-1}{\frac{Y+X-z}{X}-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty X^{-n-1}(Y+X-z)^n$$
since the rhs can be identified with an element in $k[T]^h_{(T-z)}\otimes k[Y][[\frac{1}{X}]]$ which is "almost" $k[T]_{(T-z)}^h\otimes k[X,Y,\frac{1}{X}]$. Is there any way to adapt this "almost" argument to my case?

Comment: Two questions : 1) why $z\neq 0$ ? My first reflex would be to take $T'=T-z$ so that we can assume that $z=0$, so I really don't understand this restriction. 2) What is $W$ ? It appears in the left hand side but not in the right hand side. Unless it means something particular, the rings cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: Yeah that's a typo, W=Y.

Comment: @Roland: yes $z=0$ is ok, I've edited.